# Unable to Reverse an Integer Array

Tags: c#, arrays, reverse

I am currently creating a Legend component that maps text onto a gradient-looking legend that looks like this:

[image]

The central piece of code looks like the below (omitting the `graphics` declaration code snippets, as that's not the main piece):

```
        int numberOfItems = 10;
        int increment = (int) Math.Round((max - min), 0);
        int step = increment / numberOfItems;
```

Array that stores the `step` into an `integer` array the size of `10`.

```
        int[] legend = new int[numberOfItems];
        for (int i = 0; i < legend.Length; i++) {
            legend[i] = step * i;
        }
```

String Reversal Code Snippet

```
        for (int i = (legend.Length - 1); i >= 0; i--) {
            g.DrawString(legend[i].ToString(), drawFontX, Brushes.White, ((newWidth / 2) - 5), (newHeight / 10) + (verticalDistance * i), stringFormatTimes);
        }
```

I have also tried:

```
        legend.Reverse();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
            g.DrawString(legend[i].ToString(), drawFontX, Brushes.White, ((newWidth / 2) - 5), (newHeight / 10) + (verticalDistance * i), stringFormatTimes);    
        }
```

As you can tell, I am trying to have the graph render the text from the largest value to the lowest, instead of what it is doing now, which is 0 - 1080.

My issue is, despite using both array reversal methods, I have been unable to reverse the `legend` array. I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`legend.Reverse` binds to `Enumerable.Reverse` which returns you a copy. This should teach you not to mutate state if you don't have to. Instead, create new data from old data.

```
var legendContents =
 Enumerable.Range(0, numberOfItems)
 .Select(i => step * i)
 .Reverse()
 .Select(i => new { Text = i.ToString(), Y = (newHeight / 10) + (verticalDistance * i) }
 .ToArray();

//at this point you can easily examine all draw operations in the debugger

var xPos = ((newWidth / 2) - 5);
foreach (var legendItem in legendContents)
 g.DrawString(legendItem.Text, drawFontX, Brushes.White, xPos, legendItem.Y, stringFormatTimes);
```

Use a functional programming style. Much code saved, very readable now and easy to change.

Comment: Are there any benefits to your solution and the ones Dan and Dave Bish suggested?

Comment: There are multiple Reverse methods in the framework. Which one is picked depends on the exact type of the receiver. You might accidentally call List.Reverse for example. This is a design flaw in the BCL.

Comment: Excuse me but did you look at my previous question's code snippets to implement the things below the array reversal =P?

Comment: That's rather funny actually, unless I'm not in on the joke. I also named my items xPos and stringFormatTimes. Anyways - thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
legend = legend.Reverse().ToArray();
```

The problem is that the `Reverse` method you are using doesn't change the original object; it creates a new object with the items from the original in reverse order.  But you weren't saving the result of the `Reverse` method.  It was just being ignored.  If you reassign the value of the `legend` variable to the result of the `Reverse` method, this should fix your problem.

Another option would be to use a `List<int>`:

```
List<int> legend = new List<int>(numberOfItems);
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
    legend.Add(step * i);
}

//...

legend.Reverse();
```

Here you would be calling the `Reverse` method on the `List<T>` class which does change the order of the calling list instead of returning a new instance.

Answer (score 2):

You missed your assignment:

```
legend = legend.Reverse().ToArray();
```